# canvas.toDataURL() blocked on IE9, URL is same origin

Tags: javascript, image, canvas

So as part of handling downloads of some reports on my site, images are exported from the site to a script on the same domain to generate a download, however it appears to only throw a SecurityError.

This is not similar to other questions, strictly because the source of the image is the same domain. I'm not pulling it from another site.

I surmise this has something to do with IE9 treating data URLs as tainted and rejecting my efforts. It's the only thing I could guess.

Code:

```
      //i is part of a loop, this is referring to a Vue instance, but that shouldn't matter
      var svg = this.charts[i].getSVG(); //Highcharts method.
      var svgSize = {height: this.charts[i].chartHeight ,width: this.charts[i].chartWidth};//svg.getBoundingClientRect();
      var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
      canvas.height = svgSize.height;
      canvas.width = svgSize.width;
      var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
      //Image it up
      var img = document.createElement('img');
      img.setAttribute('src', 'data:image/svg+xml;base64,' + btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(svg))));
      img.setAttribute('crossOrigin', 'anonymous');
      img.onload = function() {
        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
        //Add the image
        var url = canvas.toDataURL('image/png'); //ERROR HERE
        //url is stored into an array, irrelevant.
        //If it exists in the next element, continue;
        if(typeof self.charts[i+1] != "undefined") { self.generateChartByIdx(i+1); }
      };
```

Throws `SCRIPT5022: SecurityError`

Comment: Added the error in the console. It's all it's saying.

Comment: Tried. Didn't work unfortunately.

Comment: Yeah, all other browsers work fine. I think I found a solution though. It's a godawful solution but it works. Use canvg to just take the svg representations and replace the images with a canvas.